# jQuery multiple if else statements stuck at second condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Someone please tell me why the following script only works to the first “else if” statement?

Even if the width is below 800px I still get the 900px settings.

Here is the live code http://jsbin.com/iranof/2/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var window_width = $(window).width();  

if (window_width >= 900){
$('#adSize').attr('id','largeRectangle');    
}
else 
  if (window_width <= 800)  
  {
$('#adSize').attr('id','mediumRectangle');
}  
else 
  if (window_width <= 700)  
  {
$('#adSize').attr('id','square');
}  
else
  if (window_width <= 600)  
  {
$('#adSize').attr('id','smallSquare');
}  
else if (window_width <= 480)
{
$('#adSize').attr('id','mediumRectangle');
} 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check this link. http://jsbin.com/iranof/4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

700 <= 800. If window_width is less than 800, the first `else if` check will return `true` - and so its body will be invoked; all the other `else if` will be ignored.

Rebuild your code so that `<=` checks deal with increasing numbers:

```
else if (window_width <= 480) { ... }
else if (window_width <= 600) { ... }
else if (window_width <= 700) { ... }
else if (window_width <= 800) { ... }
```

Comment: and changing the `<=` against `>=` would mean less code refactoring btw. because you dont have to rearange the branches.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be:

```
if (window_width >= 900){   
}
else 
  if (window_width <= 800 && window_width > 700)  
  {
}  
else 
  if (window_width <= 700 && window_width > 600)  
  {
}
```

and so on... Else you other `else if` branches will be abandonded once you got into the 800 branch.

Comment: There is more simple see raina77ow answer, its more logic.

Comment: Why do you have to check BOTH for `>700` and `<=700`? Wouldn't it be easier just to reorder these checks?

Comment: @roasted More bulletproof is always better. His answer is dependent on the order... Code that depends on certain restrictions is very error prone. I would never code like this and also don't promote such a programming style.

Comment: @Christoph Code repeat is NEVER bulletproof. If these limits change (for example, it would be check for 750, not 700), BUT one forget to change it in two places instead of one, this will cause quite a subtle bug. When you introduce a redundancy, at least make it check itself: with moving out these numbers to constants, for example.

Comment: well, we could argue about that all day long I guess. changing two equal values in two adjacent `if` conditions is IMO probably far more obvious then some mysterious order which might be not obvious to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window_width >= 900)
{   
$('#adSize').attr('id','largeRectangle');
}
else 
if (window_width <= 800 && window_width > 700)  
{
$('#adSize').attr('id','mediumRectangle');
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var window_width = $(window).width();  

if (window_width >= 900){
$('#adSize').attr('id','largeRectangle');    
}
else 
  if (window_width >= 800)  
  {
$('#adSize').attr('id','mediumRectangle');
}  
else 
  if (window_width >= 700)  
  {
$('#adSize').attr('id','square');
}  
else
  if (window_width >= 600)  
  {
$('#adSize').attr('id','smallSquare');
}  
else if (window_width <= 600)
{
  $('#adSize').attr('id','mediumRectangle');
} 
});
</script>
```